# Confused as to why I can't login to Github when I know passwords and profile info are correct

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I try to force push and get the login script, enter my username and password, and even though they are correct, I get "Invalid Password" error.

It doesn't seem like I need to do any terminal stuff with it, since it seems like a simple login and I do not yet have any SSH keys associated with the account.

Does the two-factor auth mess it up? Just trying to make things work and as I type this I HAVE been checking the questions that pop up and none are of the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the two-factor auth mess it up?

Possibly: with 2FA, you need to [generate a PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) and use that token as your password.

Comment: What scopes would I need to enable for it to work seamlessly with VSCode?

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. My only concern is that the author is listed as my private "username" i.e. my home directory. In OSX /Users/<me> That is the only thing left I need to fix

Comment: @IBP For the commit author, you need to setup `git config --global user.name` and `git config --global user.email`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.